# Inheriting from a templated class with operator overloading. ambiguous overload for 'operator*'

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

I am trying, for learning purposes, to work with templated classes and inheritance. One of the things is that I want my classes to be able to use operators such as `+=`, `+`, `-=`, `-`, `*`, `*=`, etc. For such purpose, I have developed a class that is basically an array of data:

```
template<typename T, int N>
class Array
{
public:
    // Constructor
    Array( T value = T(0))
    {
        /* Initialize the array with the same value everywhere */
    }
    template<typename M>
    Array(const Array<M,N>& other)
    {
        /* Copy constructor allowing for type change */
    }

    // Destructor
    ~Array()
    {
        /* no need to call any destructor since it is a smart pointer */    
    }

    // Product
    template<typename M>
    Array<T,N>& operator*=(const M& rhs)
    {
        /* implementation */
    }
    template<typename M>
    friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
    {
        /* implementation */
    }
    template<typename M>
    friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
    {
        /* implementation */
    }
    Array<T,N>& operator*=(const Array<T,N>& rhs)
    {
        /* implementation */
    }
    friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const Array<T,N>& rhs)
    {
        /* implementation */
    }

    // String
    std::string str() const
    {
        /* return a string containing the array */
    }

private:
    std::shared_ptr<T> data_;
    size_t n_;
};
```

I have tested this class using the following code without any problem:

```
// Test friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const Array<T,N>& rhs)
Array<double,2> array1(1);
std::cout<<"array1: "<<array1.str()<<std::endl;
Array<double,2> array2(2);
std::cout<<"array2: "<<array2.str()<<std::endl;
Array<int,2> array3 = array1*array2;
std::cout<<"array3: array1*array2"<<array3.str()<<std::endl;

// Test friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
Array<double,2> array4 = 2*array1;
std::cout<<"array4: 2*array1"<<array4.str()<<std::endl;

// Test friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
Array<double,2> array5 = array1*5;
std::cout<<"array5: array1*3"<<array5.str()<<std::endl;
```

Then, I inherit from this array to create an array of size 3 with a specific member function

```
template<typename T>
class Vector3: public Array<T,3>
{
public:
    // Use Array constructors
    using Array<T,3>::Array;

    // Specific function
    template<typename M>
    Vector3 crossProduct(const Vector3& other)
    {
        /* implementation */
    }
};
```

And I want to use it as follows (note that it is the same as before with `Array<T,N>` but with `Vector3<T>`):

```
// Test friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const Array<T,N>& rhs)
Vector3<double> vector1(1);
std::cout<<"vector1: "<<vector1.str()<<std::endl;
Vector3<double> vector2(2);
std::cout<<"vector2: "<<vector2.str()<<std::endl;
Vector3<int> vector3 = vector1*vector2;
std::cout<<"vector3: vector1*vector2"<<vector3.str()<<std::endl;

// Test friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
Vector3<double> vector4 = 2*vector1;
std::cout<<"vector4: 2*vector1"<<vector4.str()<<std::endl;

// Test friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
Vector3<double> vector5 = vector1*5;
std::cout<<"vector5: vector1*3"<<vector5.str()<<std::endl;
```

When I compile, I get the following erros:

```
error: ambiguous overload for 'operator*' (operand types are 'Vector3<double>' and 'Vector3<double>')
     Vector3<int> vector3 = vector1*vector2;
                                   ^
note: candidates are:
note: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = int; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
note: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = int; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
note: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
note: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
note: Array<double, 3> operator*(const Array<double, 3>&, const Array<double, 3>&)
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
     Vector3<double> vector4 = 2*vector1;
                                 ^
note: candidate 1: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = int; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
note: candidate 2: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = int; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
     Vector3<double> vector4 = 2*vector1;
                                 ^
note: candidate 1: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = int; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
note: candidate 2: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = double; int N = 2]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
     Vector3<double> vector4 = 2*vector1;
                                 ^
note: candidate 1: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = int; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
note: candidate 2: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = int; int N = 2]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
     Vector3<double> vector4 = 2*vector1;
                                 ^
note: candidate 1: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = int; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
note: candidate 2: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
     Vector3<double> vector5 = vector1*5;
                                       ^
note: candidate 1: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = int; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
note: candidate 2: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = int; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
     Vector3<double> vector5 = vector1*5;
                                       ^
note: candidate 1: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = int; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
note: candidate 2: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = double; int N = 2]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
     Vector3<double> vector5 = vector1*5;
                                       ^
note: candidate 1: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = int; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
note: candidate 2: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = int; int N = 2]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
warning: ISO C++ says that these are ambiguous, even though the worst conversion for the first is better than the worst conversion for the second: [enabled by default]
     Vector3<double> vector5 = vector1*5;
                                       ^
note: candidate 1: Array<T, N> operator*(const Array<T, N>&, const M&) [with M = int; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
                       ^
note: candidate 2: Array<T, N> operator*(M, const Array<T, N>&) [with M = Vector3<double>; T = double; int N = 3]
     friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
                       ^
```

I do not understand why with the inherited class I get the errors and with the base class I do not. I have tryied adding `using Array<T,3>::operator*`, but then the compiler complains as wel from this line:

```
error: no members matching 'Array<double, 3>::operator*' in 'class Array<double, 3>'
     using Array<T,3>::operator*;
                               ^
```

Anybody can explain me why the operators are not properly resolved in the child class but they are in the base class? If I have to do something like `using Array<T,3>::operator...` how should I write it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are getting these errors because when compiler tries to match operator parameters it will be force to perform an extra down casting to base class while it gets exact matches when calling the same operators on instances of base class. You should put additional restrictions on type of `M` using `::std::enable_if`, like this:

```
template
<
     typename M
,    typename TEnable = typename ::std::enable_if_t
     <
         ::std::is_integral<M>::value
         ||
         ::std::is_floating_point<M>::value
     >
>
```

There is no `operator*` in `Array<T,3>` class as you declare * operators as non-member friend function templates.

Answer (score 0):

After the tip that VTT provided, I was able to fix the code. Since I do not use c++14, I have managed to do it without the `std::enable_if_t`. Here is the final operators:

```
// Product
template<typename M, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Array<T,N>,M>::value>::type>
Array<T,N>& operator*=(const M& rhs)
{
    /* implementation */
}
template<typename M, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Array<T,N>,M>::value>::type>
friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const M& rhs)
{
    /* implementation */
}
template<typename M, typename std::enable_if<!std::is_base_of<Array<T,N>,M>::value>::type>
friend Array<T,N> operator*( M lhs, const Array<T,N>& rhs)
{
    /* implementation */
}
Array<T,N>& operator*=(const Array<T,N>& rhs)
{
    /* implementation */
}
friend Array<T,N> operator*(const Array<T,N>& lhs,const Array<T,N>& rhs)
{
    /* implementation */
}
```

Hopefully this will help somebody else.